# OpenMP: Fortran: Add Reduction on a Matrix

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a large N-by-T element matrix named DATA (T is the number of threads).  I want to add elements of each row of DATA to produce a single N element output vector named SUM.  This is the serial version of the code:

```
  DO j=1,N
      DO i=1,T
          SUM(j) = SUM(j) + DATA(j, i)
      END DO
  END DO
```

What's the fastest way to compute this in OpenMP?  I know I can use a PARALLEL-DO-REDUCTION on the inner loop and I assume the compiler would use a binary tree algorithm to add all elements of that row.  If so, each row will require log(T) steps to compute, and that's good.  But you would start and stop that binary-tree reduction N times, and I'm concerned those N separate binary-tree add reductions will create lots of overhead.

Is there a faster way?  I want to run a single binary tree add-reduction algorithm where each step adds together entire columns of DATA, as opposed to elements of a single row of DATA.  So there are still log(T) steps, but each step does N additions instead of 1 addition.  And I want this to happen in parallel.  Is there an OpenMP construct to do this easily?  Or do I have to manually code it myself?

EDIT: After a few days of discussion I changed the order of the loop bounds and I'm posting a full FORTRAN program below.  For the real application, the actual values of N and T are about (6000, 40) and that runs 10000 times inside an outer loop.  However, (6000, 40) runs in about a millisecond and that's too fast to profile.  So in the code below, I changed those numbers to (6000000, 40).  Also the visual editor has problems with the macro define statements for N/T so they don't appear in the code listing.

#define N   6000000
#define T   40

```
  PROGRAM AddArray

  INTEGER :: i, j
  REAL, DIMENSION (:,:), POINTER :: p_DATA
  REAL, DIMENSION (:), POINTER :: p_sum
  INTEGER :: cr, cm, s1, s2, count_rate, count_max

  call system_clock(count_rate=cr)
  call system_clock(count_max=cm)

  ALLOCATE (p_DATA(N, T))
  ALLOCATE (p_sum(N))

  !! Initialize data
  DO i=1,T
      p_sum(j) = 0.0
      DO j=1,N
          p_DATA(j, i) = j
      END DO
  END DO

  !! Add Reduction on rows of DATA[]
  call system_clock(s1)
  DO i=1,T
      DO j=1,N
          p_sum(j) = p_sum(j) + p_DATA(j, i)
      END DO
  END DO
  call system_clock(s2)
  WRITE(0,*) "TIMING: Loop 2: ", (s2-s1) * 1

  DEALLOCATE (p_DATA)
  DEALLOCATE (p_sum)

  END
```

Comment: 1) Your serial code is likely inefficient because of the poor memory access pattern on `DATA`; 2) if you openmp-ize the inner loop, the threads will have virtually nothing to do apart from the reduction itself: again it will be inefficient; 3) swapping the 2 loops and openmp-izing the outer loop will do what you want, but I doubt you can get any speed-up anyway.

Comment: @PierU the outer index is the parallel one. I think without any loop swapping the speedup should be very nice, at least in `N` is large enough.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout yes, but the spatial locality in the inner loop is horrible. You'll get as much improvement in serial by fixing that as you will by parallelising the outer loop. If both are fixed I agree it should perform well.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried to parallelize the original outer loop with OpenMP, and it did not help.   I tried lots of things and the only thing that helped was switching the loop bounds as PierU said.  Other than that, why is this so difficult?  Is it because this code is memory bound?  Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: Although it depends on your CPU, I would say that this kind of code is typically memory bound. Also, reductions on arrays can have a significant cost, and your code is almost only a reduction.

Comment: If you want advice on improving the code with the loop indices the right way around don't hesitate to ask a new question - but please, please provide a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with representative values for `N` and `T`.

Comment: As for indexing the basic rule in Fortran for performance is the inner loop should go down the first index. This is because (very briefly) Fortran stores its arrays as row major, and as a result going down the columns (i.e. first index) results in linear accessing of the memory, which is the most efficient.

Comment: @IanBush Your description is correct, but this is actually "column major" (i.e. the memory layout is first (major) by column, then by row; row/column refering to the usual convention matrix indeces in maths).

Comment: I understand how row-major and column-major works.  I didn't think it would matter in this case because T is small enough T cache lines can all be in cache at the same time.  Yes, I access DATA[] in the wrong order and every iteration of the inner loop causes a cache miss.  But then for the next iterations of the outer loop, there should be no cache misses for the full inner loop.  So, the above loop would run fast with either loops as the outer loop.

Comment: This is the minimal reproducible example: I put some effort into reducing the original program to this.  The only thing I left out was declaring and initialing the variables, and the Fortran header.  I can post that if you like (complete Fortran program).  Actual values for N are 125,000 and T is 96.

Comment: @PierU whoops! Too much C recently... of course you are correct, Fortran is Column major

Comment: Sow some actual code that can be independently compiled and tested with the results of your own performance measurements. There is really little point of so much discussion about one loop nest where we are not even sure how it changed since the posting.

Comment: What matters for the cache lines is not the value of T but the value of N. Accessing `DATA(j,i)` in Fortran is like accessing `data[(i-1)*N+j]` in C

Comment: Be aware that increasing the problem size for profiling and optimizing may not be the best thing to do, if real cases will be smaller. Sometimes, a bigger can can be made faster using some technique, but it won't help with a smaller one. This is not linear. Instead, it is often better to perform a realistic case many times in a row. In fact, in modern CPUs it often takes time to get the cores into the top speed (various turbo modes and switching between multiple cores priority) and it may be better to ignore a certain number of tries a and only start measuring later.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution will purely be practical without any explanations (memory access for example) from a HPC expert and even might need further improvements.**

When looking at your code I can think of two improvements that will be "merged" in the final solution that I will provide.

## Parallelization of nested for loops

The are a keyword that can be used to parallelize nested for loops:

```
!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC) COLLAPSE(1) PRIVATE(i, j)
DO i = 2,imax
    DO j = 2,jmax
        ! some instructions
    ENDDO
ENDDO
!$OMP END DO
```

## Using default SUM loop for the inner for loop

The is the `SUM` function that computes the sum over an array in fortran, you would have only one for loop, I dont know about the gains in an actual calculation:

```
  DO j=1,N
      SUM(j) = SUM(j) + SUM(DATA(j, :))
  END DO
```

## Final code by merging the two ideas

```
  !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC) PRIVATE( j)
  DO j=1,N
      SUM(j) = SUM(j) + SUM(DATA(j, :))
  END DO
  !$OMP END DO
```

**The SUM variable name need to be changed.**

But for parallel computations there are many implementations, and you should test some of them to check which one works the best for you. Given the size of your array there must be an axis that will benefit more from parallelization.

Comment: None of your solutions avoid the heavy cache trashing that results from the second index that varies in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach for your computation is something like

```
do i = 1, T
   !$OMP PARALLEL DO
   do j = 1, N
      sum(j) = sum(j) + data(j,i)
   end do
   !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
end do
```

Or:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO REDUCTION(+:sum)
do i = 1, T
   sum(:) = sum(:) + data(:,i)
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

A more explicit solution that does what you want, based on OpenMP tasks. Note that with T columns there can be only T/2 occupied threads at the same time. The code can probably be refined.

```
use omp_lib
implicit none

real, allocatable :: a(:,:), s(:)

allocate( a(10**6,16), source=1.0)

call omp_set_num_threads(8)

!$OMP PARALLEL
!$OMP MASTER
s = sumcols(a)
!$OMP END MASTER
!$OMP END PARALLEL

print*, s(1)

contains

recursive function sumcols(data) result(s)
   implicit none
   real, intent(in)  :: data(:,:)
   real, allocatable :: s(:)
   integer :: k
   real, allocatable :: s2(:)

   print*, "thread", omp_get_thread_num(), " processes", size(data,2), " columns"
   if (size(data,2) <= 2) then
      s = sum( data, dim=2 )
   else
      k = size(data,2) / 2
      !$OMP TASK SHARED(data,s)
      s = sumcols(data(:,1:k))
      !$OMP END TASK
      !$OMP TASK SHARED(data,s2)
      s2 = sumcols(data(:,k+1: ))
      !$OMP END TASK
      !$OMP TASKWAIT
      s = s + s2
   end if
end function

end
```

Output:

```
 thread           0  processes          16  columns
 thread           0  processes           8  columns
 thread           0  processes           4  columns
 thread           3  processes           8  columns
 thread           2  processes           2  columns
 thread           3  processes           4  columns
 thread           3  processes           2  columns
 thread           7  processes           4  columns
 thread           0  processes           2  columns
 thread           7  processes           2  columns
 thread           1  processes           4  columns
 thread           6  processes           2  columns
 thread           5  processes           2  columns
 thread           4  processes           2  columns
 thread           1  processes           2  columns
   16.0000000
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and the time you put into this.  However, I tried your code and both examples ran slower than the non-OpenMP version with a changed loop order (outer loop is for T and inner loop is for N).

Comment: @JB_User I'm not surprised at all. Not all computations are good candidates for parallel computing. And when they are, it can be depend a lot on the sizes and on the number of threads.